# Get string between quotes from output and put them into a array in bash

Tags: bash, curl, sed, awk, grep

I have a string from a Curl response and I want to put all of the "ids" into an bash array so I can use it later.

here is a snippet of my curl response:

> {"id":"45bcd726916e452f814ffddda8a0885b","username":"bob","email:"something@test.com"},         {"username":"bob","email:"something@test.com"},{"id":"054f765f23f14957b5bcd46a8b6f9cf1","username":"tom","email:"something2@test.com"},{"username":"bob","email:"something@test.com"},{"id":"9929928686a84e4a854c85b4ff93c1cf","username":"sam","email:"something@3test.com"},{"username":"bob","email:"something@test.com"}, ........

I would like the output to be

```
$ echo ${n[0]}
45bcd726916e452f814ffddda8a0885b
$ echo ${n[1]}
054f765f23f14957b5bcd46a8b6f9cf1
$ echo ${n[1]}
9929928686a84e4a854c85b4ff93c1cf
```

please help, I've been stuck for hours.

Comment: are there any newlines in there? It isn't clear from the formatting ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your string is in `$str`, this should work:

```
n=($(echo $str | grep -o '"id":"[^"]*"' | cut -d '"' -f4))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or at least get you started in the right direction.

```
y=0
for id in $(curl|cut -f4 -d'"')
do
  n[$y]=$id
  let y++
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works.

```
#!/bin/bash

N=() I=0

while read -r -d '}' LINE; do
    if [[ $LINE == *'{"id":"'* ]]; then
        LINE=${LINE#*'{"id":"'}
        N[I++]=${LINE%%\"*}
    fi
done < input
```

Where input could be a file or could be process substitution:

```
done < <(curl ...)
```